# Storing images in buffer

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap, buffer

I'm writing my first image editing program (c#, winforms) and I am quite bad with buffers and storing my data efficiently.
I have a folder containing pictures and load the files into a `string[]` via `FolderBrowserDialog`:

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
```

I always display one of the images in a picture box. I have various functions that apply e.g. a filter on the displayed image. All my functions work on Bitmaps, and all of my functions start basically by calling another function:

```
Bitmap bmp = GetImage();
```

and:

```
Image GetImage()
{
    FileStream imageStream = new FileStream(Convert.ToString(files[SelIndex]), FileMode.Open);
    Image image = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
    imageStream.Close();
    return image;
}
```

Whenever I call one of my functions (for example because I want to display a different image and see how the filter applies there) I get a painful lag before the new picture is displayed. As far as I'm concerned, everytime I call one of my functions, it reaches way down into the original folder where the pictures are and gets the data from there, and I believe that is the reason for the lag.
**First of: is that correct? Secondly: what would be a way to avoid this?** I could imagine saving the data in some sort of buffer?

My functions/filters are very basic and I don't use the `SetPixel` method but:

```
BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

byte[] bytes = new byte[data.Height * data.Stride];

Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

//whatever my filter is

Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, data.Scan0, bytes.Length);

bmp.UnlockBits(data);
```

since it is way faster, so the lag shouldn't come from that.

**edit:** also, I'm working with .tif files, roughly 12 MB each, definitely part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the file operations are expensive.  They involve two relatively slow operations:  reading data from disk and decompressing data.

First of all, consider this simple alternative to all the FileStream stuff you have written.

```
Bitmap input = new Bitmap(pathToFile);
```

Also, your `GetImage` function is really a `LoadImageFromDisk` function.  So the first thing to do is to make sure that you only do this once and keep the input Bitmap object in memory and reuse it.  When calling LockBits on the input image, use ReadOnly access.

If you want to make a modification (like applying an image filter) then store the results of this filter operation in a new *output* image, rather than overwriting the original image in memory.  Then if you want to change details of the filter, you still have the original hanging around.

```
Bitmap output = new Bitmap(input.Width, input.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
```

And when you LockBits on the output image, use the WriteOnly access.

Also, consider using an *unsafe* context to directly access the data instead of using Marshal.Copy, it'll save you a buffer copy.

And finally, whatever your filter is, see if you can make use of Parallel.For to operate on it line at a time and make use of all your processors.

Comment: Already tried to implement some of your suggestions and works perfectly so far, thanks alot.
What do you mean by unsafe context to access the data?

Comment: [unsafe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe) allows you to create a `byte*` pointer from the IntPtr of BitmapData.Scan0 and directly access the data.  You have to [allow unsafe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/unsafe-compiler-option) in your project settings; it is disabled by default.